# How do I convert MJD(julian date) to UTC using astropy?

Tags: python, astropy

I've tried stuff on the astropy website but still need help. Anyone out there got a clue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time/index.html is a good place to start. There you will learn about the distinction between a time *format* like MJD and a time *scale* like UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this returns the desired result.

```
from astropy.time import Time

# Start with some time in modified julian date (MJD)
mjd = 58134.09699299725

# Convert to Julian Date
jd = mjd + 2400000.5

# Convert to astropy Time object
t = Time(jd, format='jd')

# Convert to datetime
utc = t.to_datetime()
```

Answer (score 0):

MJD is a date format whereas UTC is a time scale, so I assume you mean convert MJD to another standard format like ISO.

If your MJD time is already in UTC scale, you can pass to an astropy Time object (like one of the above answers) and directly call it as a MJD format (can avoid the MJD to JD conversion). Additionally, if your epoch is in another scale (like TDB or TT) you can specify that when passing to the Time class and it will be able to convert for you. The default scale astropy Time uses is UTC.

```
from astropy.time import Time

# Start with some time in modified julian date (MJD)
mjd = 58134.09699299725

# create Time object (no JD conversion!)
t = Time(mjd, format='mjd')    # --> if MJD not in UTC, can add scale flag: scale='tdb'

# return in ISO format 
print(t.iso)                  # ---> '2018-01-16 02:19:40.195'

# can show in different scales
print(t.tdb.iso)              # ---> '2018-01-16 02:20:49.379'

# can also return Time object as JD
print(t.jd)                   # ---> 2458134.5969929975
```

For a full list of the time formats and scales you can use with astropy Time, you can run the commands `Time.FORMATS` and `Time.SCALES` respectively.